# XCode - how to rename Core Data xcdatamodeld model internals?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I copied my data model from one project to another. I can rename the .xcdatamodeld file, and load it using the new name. However, when I edit the data model, the breadcrumbs still show me that inside it is an actual model, still under the old name (with green checkbox). I'm using automatically generated classes for entities from the model (codegen > class definition)

I tried renaming the files in finder, but that stops the model from loading.

**Is there a way to rename the internals of a .xcdatamodeld without having to migrate everything to a new model?**

However, when I open the [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to rename actual .xcdatamodel files or only the .xcdatamodeld one?

If you right click on your .xcdatamodeld file there's an [option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMr0H.png): 'Show Package Contents'. It will show you the list of all .xcdatamodel files inside.

Each .xcdatamodel represents a specific version of your DB. Try to rename those files and don't forget about .xccurrentversion file there - it contains xml with the name of your current model version (it's hidden so be sure you can view hidden files in Finder). After that you can add the renamed xcdatamodeld file to your project.

Edit: The .xccurrentversion file name shouldn't change, only the name of the current version model inside (it's basically plain xml file): [image]

Comment: I tried renaming the files and the .xccurrentversion, but XCode refuses to open the renamed model (click on it, and nothing happens)

Comment: That's strange, did you add xcdatamodeld file to your project after you renamed it or before? And just to avoid misunderstanding about .xccurrentversion file - the file itself shouldn't be renamed, it's just for the current model version name inside it, I'll edit my answer about this.

Comment: Yes, I changed the reference inside that file. Unable to open the file anymore. It's not a big deal

Comment: Ok, are you able to open the model directly from Finder? By double-clicking on the  xcdatamodeld file and xcdatamodel files inside it? If those files are opened in Xcode without issues I'd recommend to remove and add again the xcdatamodeld in your project because it might simply loose reference for it.

Comment: I had the same problem as Alex, removing and adding file again in Xcode solved the problem. Thank you ScorpiCon.